# Remove the text in the cells having only those numbers and name the row names

Tags: r

Using `trees` dataset.

```
data(trees)
```

Each column has the values of summary including its titles Min,Max,1st Quartile and so on.. But only numbers should be present in the corresponding cells and that names should be named as row names in column for whole dataset.

[image]

Need Output like this

[image]

Comment: Please show few lines of your data to make it reproducible.

Comment: need to make the output like above uploaded pic naming row names

Comment: The output you showed is based on applying `summary` directly on the dataset.  I posted a solution showing the problem.

Comment: don't post pictures of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can apply `summary` on each of the columns separately by looping with `sapply`.

```
data(trees)
sapply(trees, summary)
#         Girth Height Volume
# Min.     8.30     63  10.20
# 1st Qu. 11.05     72  19.40
# Median  12.90     76  24.20
# Mean    13.25     76  30.17
# 3rd Qu. 15.25     80  37.30
# Max.    20.60     87  77.00
```

The OP's output may have resulted from applying the `summary` directly on the whole dataset.

```
summary(trees)
#     Girth           Height       Volume     
# Min.   : 8.30   Min.   :63   Min.   :10.20  
# 1st Qu.:11.05   1st Qu.:72   1st Qu.:19.40  
# Median :12.90   Median :76   Median :24.20  
# Mean   :13.25   Mean   :76   Mean   :30.17  
# 3rd Qu.:15.25   3rd Qu.:80   3rd Qu.:37.30  
# Max.   :20.60   Max.   :87   Max.   :77.00
```